# How to change name or hide "New" tab in top nav bar in pligg cms?

Tags: content-management-system, pligg

I want to rename the "New" tab in top navigation bar in header.tpl but after i rename and save it, nothing changed and an error 404 page appears. please help me I want to hide the New tab in nav bar, which is not working...thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the word "New" you should:

1. Login to your **Admin CP**.
2. Expand the **Modules** menu.
3. Click **Modify Language**.
4. In the **Filter Text** box type New.

There are quite a few you need to change if you want your new word shown everywhere. These are the values I have changed:

- PLIGG_Visual_Search_Status_New
- PLIGG_Visual_Pligg_Queued
- PLIGG_Visual_RSS_Queued
- PLIGG_Visual_Breadcrumb_Unpublished_Tab
- PLIGG_Visual_Breadcrumb_Unpublished
- PLIGG_Visual_Breadcrumb_Queued
- PLIGG_Visual_User_NewsUnPublished
- PLIGG_Visual_AdminPanel_New
- PLIGG_Visual_AdminPanel_Mark_New
- PLIGG_Visual_EditStory_Email_NewText

Or, to **hide** the New tab you should:

1. Edit `templates\bootstrap\header.tpl`.
2. Find and Remove `<li {if $pagename eq "new"}class="active"{/if}><a href="{$URL_new}">{#PLIGG_Visual_Pligg_Queued#}</a></li>`.

Comment: lain, that worked well, thanks a lot...:)